# are MySQL functions implemented in the client or server?

Tags: mysql

Are MySQL functions such as `DATEDIFF()` implemented in the client libraries or the server?

The reason I'm asking, is because I need to use some functions that are only available in v. 5.7, and I want to know if I only need to update the client libraries to use them?

Comment: Why did someone vote this question down? This was an interesting question and made me search for answers! :-) Voting up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this github-search](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/search?q=DATEDIFF) in code of MySQL.

The function is implemented on the server side. Only server and test code contain references to the function.

Answer (score 2):

DATEDIFF(), indeed everything written inside an SQL statement, is implemented on the server.

Comment: One note from my side: your answer is correct (I think), BUT it does not prove that the use case that Donal is asking for is working: the client could still have references to the function in code... .

Comment: While it is technically possible for the client to parse and rewrite the SQL before presenting it the server, I see no reason why this would ever be a good idea - perhaps you can provide an example of such an implementation?